# RESTful API with # fragment expansion in URI Template (RFC 6570)

Tags: rest, restful-url, rfc

I have a RESTful API spec for a new project from another company and it refers to RFC6570 and the use of Fragment Expansion `{#var}` in the URI Template when making requests to their API.

The URI templates look like:

`PUT https://api.acme.com/order{#meta*}{?order_number}` or `GET https://api.acme.com/orders{#meta*}` (note the difference with order/orders).

They mention 'if the metadata stored on your system looks like this:'

```
{
  "meta": {
    "customer": "1234",
    "state": "open"
  },
  "order_number": "0003"
}
```

This is then translated into requests like `PUT https://api.acme.com/order#customer=1234,state=open?order_number=0003` or `GET https://api.acme.com/orders#customer=1234,state=open`.

The URL fragments, e.g. `#customer=1234,state=open` are meant to be used as some kind of metadata filtering or context for the request?

Postman, `curl` and browser requests appear to strip out everything after the `#` before sending to the server. Is that expected behaviour and described in an RFC somewhere? Does that mean these RESTful URLs are invalid?

What is the proper use case for the `{#var}` fragment expansion in URL Templates?

Comment: We've found https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.1 that states _The target URI excludes the reference's fragment component, if any, since fragment identifiers are reserved for client-side processing_ and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5 that states _The query component is indicated by the first question mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character_. I'm assuming this means the URL is invalid from an RFC standpoint, would still like to know if # Fragment Expansion makes any sense in a RESTful design and/or what the intended use cases are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Postman, curl and browser requests appear to strip out everything after the # before sending to the server. Is that expected behaviour and described in an RFC somewhere?

Yes, it is described in [RFC 3896](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5)

> the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.

The same idea, as described by RFC 7230

---

> Does that mean these RESTful URLs are invalid?

Sort of.

`https://api.acme.com/orders#customer=1234,state=open`

That's a perfectly valid URL (see the production rules in [RFC 3986 appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A)).

Let's review the specification for [fragments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5):

> The fragment identifier component of a URI allows indirect identification of a secondary resource by reference to a primary resource and additional identifying information.  The identified secondary resource may be some portion or subset of the primary resource, some view on representations of the primary resource, or some other resource defined or described by those representations.

The [HTTP definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.1) is a bit clearer:

> The optional fragment component allows for indirect identification of a secondary resource

So for practice, let's look at the identifier for the fragment specification itself

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5

What we have here are identifiers for two resources: the "primary resource" is the web page itself, which is identified by the sequence of characters prior to the fragment delimiter -- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986 ; then we have the secondary resource *within* that primary resource, `section-3.5` tells us what to look for in the primary resource.  So the browser knows to (a) download the primary resource, and then (b) upon discovering that the primary resource has a `text/html` representation, knows how to dig through the html tags to find the tag that matches the fragment.  The browser can then jump directly to the correct location in the document.

In your example, https://api.acme.com/orders is the primary resource, and `customer=1234,state=open` is the fragment used to identify some resource within the representation of the primary resource.

BUT

RFC 7230 defines the [request line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) of HTTP

```
method SP request-target SP HTTP-version CRLF
```

Where [request-target](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3) is in turn defined as

```
     request-target = origin-form
                    / absolute-form
                    / authority-form
                    / asterisk-form
```

The two that are of interest to us are [origin-form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.1) and [absolute-form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.2).  Both are defined by RFC 7230

```
origin-form    = absolute-path [ "?" query ]
absolute-form  = absolute-URI
```

where [absolute-URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.3) is defined in RFC 3986

> Some protocol elements allow only the absolute form of a URI without a fragment identifier.

```
absolute-URI  = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ]
```

This is all consistent with the restriction on [target-uri](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.1)

> The target URI excludes the reference's fragment component, if any, since fragment identifiers are reserved for client-side processing

---

> What is the proper use case for the {#var} fragment expansion in URL Templates?

Trying to construct a link to a secondary resource, in particular as a collaboration of two pieces of code; one piece of coding knowing the values for the template variables but not knowing where they are supposed to go (and in particular, which variables belong in the fragment), and another piece of code knowing where in the URI each of the different variables is supposed to appear, but not knowing what the values are.

In other words, it's exactly the same sort of thing we are doing when we create a URI template to allow the production of the identifier of a primary resource, but also allowing variable expansion in the fragment element as well.

```
http://example.org/people/bob
http://example.org/people#bob
```